# where exists - all - group by?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause, exists

I use SQL Server 2008 R2.

I have a weird problem as following. I have a table as shown in

[image]

I need to write such a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE Field2 IN (96,102)
```

in this query, `WHERE Field2 IN (96,102)` gives me 96 or 102 or both!

More over, I would like to return rows that contains 96 and 102 at the same time!

Is there any suggestion? please write result oriented...

Answer (score 2):

I have made a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f57d8) for this..

```
create table a (id int, val int)
go
insert into a select 1, 22
insert into a select 1, 122
insert into a select 2, 22
insert into a select 3, 122
insert into a select 4, 22
insert into a select 4, 122
```

then select like this

```
select count(distinct id), id
from a
where val in (22, 122)
group by id
having count(id) > 1
```

EDIT: count(distinct id) will only show distinct counts..

Comment: It seems `(1,22),(1,22),..` input would throw that off?

Comment: Wrong solution ... but +1 for the sqlfiddle idea!

Comment: thanks for your interest, but Unfortunately, this is not solution for me. because, if there is two rows for just (22) it willl count as 2, too :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:

Here's a sqlfiddle example (thanks to Mark Kremers):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/df201/1

```
create table mytable (field1 int, field2 int)
go
insert into mytable values (199201, 84)
insert into mytable values (199201, 96)
insert into mytable values (199201, 102)
insert into mytable values (199201, 103)
insert into mytable values (581424, 96)
insert into mytable values (581424, 84)
insert into mytable values (581424, 106)
insert into mytable values (581424, 122)
insert into mytable values (687368, 79)
insert into mytable values (687368, 96)
insert into mytable values (687368, 102)                                                       
insert into mytable values (687368, 104)                            
insert into mytable values (687368, 106)
```

Here's the query:

```
select distinct a.field1 from
( select field1 from mytable where field2=96) a
  inner join 
( select field1 from mytable where field2=102) b
  on a.field1 = b.field1
```

And here are the results:

```
FIELD1
199201
687368
```

Finally, here's a simplified version of the query (thans to pst):

```
select distinct a.field1 from  mytable a 
inner join mytable b   
  on a.field1 = b.field1 
where a.field2=96 and b.field2=102
```

Comment: thanks for your interest, but unbfortunately, this is not what I want. not just two vairables as (96,102) for field2, but also user can select three variables for field2, such as (96,102,104) for field2, in this case result query should be 671982 as field1.

Answer (score 1):

Use a self-join? Not the most tidy, but I think it works well for 2 values

```
SELECT *
FROM T R1
JOIN T R2                        -- join table with itself
ON R1.F1 = R2.F1                 -- where the first field is the same
WHERE R1.F2 = 96 AND R2.F2 = 102 -- and each has one of the required values
```

(T = Table, Rx = Relation Alias, Fx = Field)

If there can be an arbitrary number of fields, this can be solved as

```
CREATE TABLE #T (id int, val int)
GO
INSERT INTO #T (id, val)
VALUES
  (1, 22), (1, 22),     -- no,  only 22 (but 2 records)
  (2, 22), (2, 122),    -- yes, both values (only)
  (3, 122),             -- no,  only 122
  (4, 22), (4,122),     -- yes, both values ..
  (4, 444), (4, null),     -- and extra values
  (5, 555)              -- no,  neither value
GO
-- Using DISTINCT over filtered results first, as
-- SQL Server 2008 does not support HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT F1, F2)
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, val
      FROM #T
      WHERE val IN (22, 122)) AS R1
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(id) >= 2 -- or 3 or ..
GO
-- Or a similar variation, as can COUNT(DISTINCT ..)
-- in the SELECT of a GROUP BY
SELECT id
FROM (SELECT id, COUNT(DISTINCT val) as ct
      FROM #T
      WHERE val IN (22, 122)
      GROUP BY id) AS R1
WHERE ct >= 2 -- or 3 or ..
GO
```

For larger `IN (..)` sizes, say above 20 values, it *may* be advisable to use a separate table or table-value and a `JOIN` for performance reasons.

Comment: thanks for your interest, but unbfortunately, this is not what I want. not just two vairables as (96,102) for field2, but also user can select three variables for field2, such as (96,102,104) for field2, in this case result query should be 671982 as field1. according to your query, I have to write as: SELECT *
FROM T R1, T R2, T R3
WHERE R1.F1=R2.F1 AND R1.F1=R3.F1 AND R1.F2 = 96 AND R2.F2 = 102 AND R3.F2=104 ??????? rigth? if user select four variables for field2, we will add "T R4" to from section and "R1.F1=R4.F1 AND R4.F2=XXX " and so on... is there any other solution for this???

Comment: @Mustafa Yes, it becomes very tedious :-) I have added a variant of Mark's answer to address this, as well as the distinctness issue(s).

Answer (score 0):

Try from your original query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Field1 
FROM MYTABLE 
WHERE rtrim(ltrim(cast(Field2 as varchar))) IN ('96','102')
```